# Execution Timeout Expired in C# Web Application

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I didnt mentioned Timeout in "command timeout", "Web.Config file" nor "SQL server".

But whenever method runs, i will get below error. Please have a look and let know if your aware of this kind issues. Find detail error below.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> 
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at DanskeBankGroup.DJM.DataAccess.BatchDO.DJMAnonymizeApplicant(input input)
>   at DanskeBankGroup.DJM.Business.BatchBO.anonymizeApplicant(input input)  ClientConnectionId:1cb8c30c-c49c-4fbd-8b92-53dd019e4cd4  Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11

Comment: you need to check first your sqlstatement in sqlserver, is the query get more time in sqlserver. if yes, then do it fast at sqlserver side first. if not, then write your code here or increase your timeout time.

Comment: Did you ever find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use CommandTimeout property in your SqlCommand object:

```
    command.CommandTimeout=0
```

default timeout is 30 secs